# Issue with .htaccess and multiple rewrite rules and conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$|.*css$|.*js$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (^.*) http://d14t2ycfqndlt4.cloudfront.net/$1 [R=301,
```

the last 2 lines dont work, althouh when i remove the first cond above, id does work...

what is the problem? thanks!

Comment: @Death I agree - just put the last 2 lines before the other RewriteConds and you should be set

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://d14t2ycfqndlt4.cloudfront.net/$1 [R=301,...]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [NC,L]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [NC,L]
```

---

Note the regular expressions are a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is your corrected and cleaned up `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule \.(?:jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ http://d14t2ycfqndlt4.cloudfront.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```